# Bootstrap navbar stuck in mobile display

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav

The navbar I have is stuck in its mobile display and I am not sure what is causing this? http://jsfiddle.net/enL35t1q/

Navbar

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
     <!--Search Bar-->
        <form class="form-inline" method = "GET" action = "{% url 'search' %}" >
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="query"  type="text" placeholder="Zip Code or City/Town">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success text-white my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
</nav>
```

Comment: have you followed Bootstrap documentation to implement the navbar?

Comment: this is literally from the bootstrap website except i changed the links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong version of bootstrap. you are using bootstrap stable version code with stylesheet links of alpha version.

Chcek this for latest links: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/enL35t1q/12/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
</li>
</ul>
<!--Search Bar-->
<form class="form-inline" method = "GET" action = "{% url 'search' %}" >
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="query"  type="text" placeholder="Zip Code or City/Town">
<button class="btn btn-outline-success text-white my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Find Jobs</button>
</form>
</nav>
```